# Find a median in Python from Excel file

Tags: python, excel, numpy, median

I am looking to find the median as floats in the Excel which is longitude and contains (-68.2288284302 ~ -159.4401397705)

However, based on my code it returns 173.3871917725 which is not make sense.. right ? It suppose to return around -91.xxxxx based on calculation in Excel.

below is my code:

```
for i in range(2, maxRow+1):        
    country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
    longitude = sheet.cell(i,6).value
    median = np.median(longitude)
    if country=="United States":
        print("United States " + str(median))
print(median)
```

below is the ss for output.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhqan.png)

So what i concern is how can i find the right number of median ?

Could anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: My first suggestion is to extract the Excel out of the picture: save the longitude values in a list. Second, this does not seem to be the way NumPy's median works: median expects a list itself, you could try to pass to it the list of values saved earlier: ```a=[]
for i in range(2, maxRow+1):
  a.append(sheet.cell(i,6).value)
a=[-73, -157, -87, -118, -122]  # suppose it's from Excel
>>> np.median(a)  # -118.0```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing median on a single value, you should build a list and then compute

```
the median:

longitude_list = []
for i in range(2, maxRow+1):        
    country = sheet.cell(i,7).value
    longitude = sheet.cell(i,6).value
    longitude_list.append(longitude)
median = np.median(longitude)
print(median)
```